# What's the difference between "management", "administration", and "moderator"/"mediator"?

Tags: differences

It looks like "moderator" is mostly used for online forums, whereas "manager" and "administrator" are used interchangeably. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Have you checked the dictionary definitions of each word?

Comment: @KillingTime Yes, but still there are some ambiguities.